# Module cannot be resolved from lib in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

If I write a class in a file in `lib`, I can find it. If I write a module in the same file, I cannot find it. Did I miss something?

The files look like:

[image: File structure]

And the file contents are:

```
class Cool
end

module Flags
  Countries = []
end
```

If I try to call them from a controller:

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def index
    Cool.new # works
    Flags::Countries # uninitialized constant MainController::Flags    
  end
end
```

Comment: Nope. I think it probably doesn't have to do with loading paths because I **can** load the "Cool" class, but not the module. I'll be trying again later today.

Answer (score 0):

Might not a solution to your specific scenario, just a few relevant points:

Rails autoloading expects classes / modules to follow namespacing rules:

```
Flags::Countries -> <autoload paths>/flags/countries.rb
```

http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/

Don't think /lib/ is a standard autoloading path, so you'll need to ensure it's added into your path.